# PowerShell Logon Script by GPO writes empty file

Tags: powershell, gpo

I'm trying to set up a simple script.
Every time a user does log in, it should execute a simple PowerShell script by the GPO I set up, the script should then gather all data from Get-ComputerInfo and write it to a file on a shared folder.

I've tried many things, like Start-Job

```
$Task = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
Get-ComputerInfo | Out-File "\\SERVER\ComputerInfo\$env:COMPUTERNAME - 
$env:USERNAME.txt" 
}
Wait-Job $Task.Name | Out-Null
```

It works great executing it on the desktop by the user, but as logon script it does not work. It creates the file, but it's empty.

My suspicion is that it does not wait until PowerShell gather all information from Get-ComputerInfo (it usually takes some seconds) and just writes an empty file.

Execution Policy, Permission for Folders, etc shouldn't be a problem, especially considering it creates the file and the script works on the desktop with a non-admin user.

Comment: For troubleshooting, add `*>&1` to the `Get-ComputerInfo` call. You can additionally include the pipeline in `try` / `catch` and send `$_` to a file in the `catch` block, to rule out terminating errors (though if `Get-ComputerInfo` created a terminating error, `Out-File` would never create an output file).

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe try with Invoke-Command instead of as a job?
`Invoke-command -ComputerName 'Localhost' -ScriptBlock { Get-ComputerInfo...`

Comment: Might also help to temporarily set `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to hide the progress bar indicator produced by `Get-ComputerInfo`